# Как включить миграцию для 2 контекстов?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, миграция

Создал проект ASP.NET MVC 5 с аутентификацией `Individual User Accounts`. Автоматически были созданы классы, строка подключения для работы с аутентификацией. Добавил свою строку подключения, свою модель, свой контекст. Пример:

```
Модель - book`. `Контекст - Contex
```

В контексте

```
DbSet book {get; set;}
```

Пытаюсь включить миграцию (`enable-migrations`), выдает ошибку

> More than one context type was found in the assembly 'MVC'. To enable
>   migrations for 'MVC.Models.Contex', use Enable-Migrations
>   -ContextTypeName MVC.Models.Contex. To enable migrations for 'MVC.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations
>   -ContextTypeName MVC.Models.ApplicationDbContext.

То есть предлагает включить миграцию только для одного контекста, но как включить для 2 контекстов? Вдруг я планирую изменять модель пользователя, например.

Comment: Поменяйте тип контекста у аутентификации на тот, что используете вы.

Comment: Самый простой способ - использовать один контекст, тот, что предлагает вам автогенератор. Вы можете добавить в него нужные модели и настроить по своему усмотрению. Вы пробовали выполнить команды, которые предложила вам студия? Возможно теперь просто нужно передать в качестве параметра имя класса контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Так как у вас несколько контекстов в рамках проекта необходимо явно указать утилите с каким именно контекстом вы желаете работать. Для этого нужно в команду добавить параметр `ContextTypeName`

Пример команды включения миграций:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MVC.Models.ApplicationDbContext -MigrationsDirectory DirectoryName
```